# NoneType from logging module Python

Tags: python

I am running this part of code successfully on the system that I wrote the code on. When testing the whole program on another computer (cloning the git), I get an error on the row starting with "logging.error".

```
import logging, logging.handlers

def uncaught_errors(exctype, value, tb):
    logging.error("\nTYPE: "+str(exctype)+"\nVALUE: "+str(value)+"\nTRACEBACK: ".join(traceback.format_tb(tb)))

sys.excepthook = uncaught_errors
```

The error states "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'error'"

Why do I get the error?

Comment: The error suggests that the variable `logging` is set to `None`.

Comment: @DavidRobinson In this code, `uncaught_errors()` will be called when any exception is raised and uncaught.

Comment: Did you *rebind* logging somewhere else in your script?

Comment: To ensure against later accidental unbinding or rebinding of name `logging`, change your `def` to `def uncaught_errors(exctype, value, tb, logging=logging):` which binds local name `logging` immediately (at `def` time) to the value global name `logging` has at that time.